# Error when installing AIF360 Package (installing package in isolated python environment in R using reticulate)

Tags: python, r, conda, miniconda, aif360

I have been trying to install the IBM AIF360 package in R. It is distributed as a Python package and so needs to be installed within a Python environment. A function from the package, install_aif360(), attempted to install AIF360 within an isolated Python environment ("r-reticulate"). I tried following all the relevant steps in this link:
https://github.com/Trusted-AI/AIF360/tree/master/aif360/aif360-r

But I keep getting errors like this

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... failed

CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to
download and install packages.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))


Error: Error creating conda environment 'r-reticulate' [exit code 1]
```

I'm very confused as to why it's doing that. Would really appreciate any help!

Thanks!

I have tried following the trouble shooting section in the link above, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is **OpenSSSL** definitely installed? Where?

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome! I don't think OpenSSL is installed on my laptop, I tried using install.packages("openssl"), however, this also did not work @MichaelRoswell

Comment: Hi Arwa, I think you need to download and install OpenSSL directly onto your machine (i.e., not an R package but software you need on the computer to be able to use your R package) https://www.openssl.org/source/